# Saving a dropdown value in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu

So im trying to save a dropdown value in my custom post type. What am I doing wrong?

Markup:

```
<li><label>Location</label><input name="tf_events_location" value="<?php echo $meta_loc; ?>" /></li>
<li><label>Band relation</label>
    <select name="tf_events_relate" id="tf_events_relate">
      <option value="">All Artists </option>
      <option value="146">Mormor</option>
      <option value="140">John Face</option>
     </select>
</li>
```

And save

```
function save_tf_events(){

global $post;

if(!isset($_POST["tf_events_location"])):
    return $post;
    endif;
    $updateloc = $_POST["tf_events_location"];
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_events_location", $updateloc);

if(!isset($_POST["tf_events_relate"])):
    return $post;
    endif;
    $updaterelate = $_POST["tf_events_relate"];
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_events_relate", $updaterelate);
}
```

My `tf_events_location` gets saved allright, but my `tf_events_relate` is not doing anything.
I think i might be getting the principle wrong ;)

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a value through for the `tf_events_relate` field?

Comment: If i select one of the options i should get their value - right?

Comment: If you select "All Artists", you ma not get a value, but if you select "John Face", you should get `140` as the value.

Comment: Yeah. And i tried all three :) With no results. When i press Publish or Update the field gets reset. And the value hasn't changed.

Comment: The field will get reset on the HTML page because you are not telling the `<select>` which option is selected. The one that was selected needs to have the `selected` attribute. It's the same idea as setting the value of the input up above. Also, is the DB getting updated?

Comment: Ahhh! Okay. Now it's making sense. The DB **IS** getting updated. Im just missing the "selected"-part. Any help on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are simply not telling the `<select>` element what `<option>` is selected when the page comes back.

There are a number of different ways to do that, some more flexible than others, but in it's most simple format with the html code you have above, this would work:

```
<li><label>Location</label><input name="tf_events_location" value="<?php echo $meta_loc; ?>" /></li>
<li><label>Band relation</label>
    <select name="tf_events_relate" id="tf_events_relate">
      <option <?php ($meta_relate == "") ? echo("selected "):; ?>value="">All Artists </option>
      <option <?php ($meta_relate == "146") ? echo("selected "):; ?>value="146">Mormor</option>
      <option <?php ($meta_relate == "140") ? echo("selected "):; ?>value="140">John Face</option>
     </select>
</li>
```

It isn't the most elegant, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you :) Semi-works as a charm - but i'll figure it out from here:)

Answer (score 0):

cdeszaq's answer will get the job done but you can simplify it with `selected()`

```
<li><label>Location</label>
    <input name="tf_events_location" value="<?php echo $meta_loc; ?>" />
</li>
<li><label>Band relation</label>
    <select name="tf_events_relate" id="tf_events_relate">
      <option value="" <?php selected( $meta_relate, '' ); ?>All Artists</option>
      <option value="146" <?php selected( $meta_relate, '146' ); ?>Mormor</option>
      <option value="140" <?php selected( $meta_relate, '140' ); ?>John Face</option>
    </select>
</li>
```